# Creating Column Based on Date Order, Rotating Dataset R

Tags: r, date, data-manipulation, tidyr

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
ID= c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C")
Date= as.Date(c("2017-09-24", "2017-09-26", "2017-09-23", "2017-09-30","2017-09-12", "2017-09-15", "2017-09-01", "2017-09-30", "2017-09-25"))
Data= c(10,5,15,20,8,9,5,6,2)
df= data.frame(ID, Date, Data)
d
  ID       Date Data
1  A 2017-09-24   10
2  A 2017-09-26    5
3  A 2017-09-23   15
4  A 2017-09-30   20
5  B 2017-09-12    8
6  B 2017-09-15    9
7  C 2017-09-01    5
8  C 2017-09-30    6
9  C 2017-09-25    2
```

I am attempting to add an additional column that is in descending order by the  Date column per ID in Descending Order, such that I have the following output:

```
   ID Order      Date   Data
1  A     3 2017-09-24   10
2  A     2 2017-09-26    5
3  A     4 2017-09-23   15
4  A     1 2017-09-30   20
5  B     2 2017-09-12    8
6  B     1 2017-09-15    9
7  C     3 2017-09-01    5
8  C     1 2017-09-30    6
9  C     2 2017-09-25    2
```

I have used striptime() and order() to attempt to get an Order column, but I am unsure of how to loop it per ID.

I am then attempting to rotate the dataframe so that each Order has its own column, and the observations are the data contained in the Data column :

```
  ID Order4 Order3 Order2 Order1
1  A     15     10      5     20
2  B                    8      9
3  C             5      2      6
```

I have tried to use tidyr's spread() to accomplish the dataset rotation, but it does not behave well since there is columns of differing length.

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

For your first question.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Order = dense_rank(desc(Date))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(ID, Order, Date, Data)
# df2
#   ID    Order Date        Data
#   <fct> <int> <date>     <dbl>
# 1 A         3 2017-09-24 10.0 
# 2 A         2 2017-09-26  5.00
# 3 A         4 2017-09-23 15.0 
# 4 A         1 2017-09-30 20.0 
# 5 B         2 2017-09-12  8.00
# 6 B         1 2017-09-15  9.00
# 7 C         3 2017-09-01  5.00
# 8 C         1 2017-09-30  6.00
# 9 C         2 2017-09-25  2.00
```

For your second question.

```
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  select(-Date) %>%
  mutate(Order = paste0("Order", Order)) %>%
  spread(Order, Data)
df3
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   ID    Order1 Order2 Order3 Order4
# * <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A      20.0    5.00  10.0    15.0
# 2 B       9.00   8.00  NA      NA  
# 3 C       6.00   2.00   5.00   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the library `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df= data.frame(ID, Date, Data)
setDT(df)[,Order:=(.N:1)[rank(Date)],by=ID][,.(ID,Order,Date,Data)]
   ID Order       Date Data
1:  A     3 2017-09-24   10
2:  A     2 2017-09-26    5
3:  A     4 2017-09-23   15
4:  A     1 2017-09-30   20
5:  B     2 2017-09-12    8
6:  B     1 2017-09-15    9
7:  C     3 2017-09-01    5
8:  C     1 2017-09-30    6
9:  C     2 2017-09-25    2
dcast(df[,order:=.(paste0("Order",Order))],ID~order,value.var = "Data")
   ID Order1 Order2 Order3 Order4
1:  A     20      5     10     15
2:  B      9      8     NA     NA
3:  C      6      2      5     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested to reshape the dataset from long to wide format where the orders of each `ID` should by numbered in decreasing order of `Date`, i.e., the most recent order is to appear in column `Order1`, the second recent order in `Order2`, etc.,

This can be achieved by `dcast()` *in one step* using the `rowid()` function:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[order(-Date)], ID ~ rowid(ID, prefix = "Order"))
```

> ```
>    ID Order1 Order2 Order3 Order4
> 1:  A     20      5     10     15
> 2:  B      9      8     NA     NA
> 3:  C      6      2      5     NA
> ```

Now, the expected result of the OP shows the `Order` columns also in descending order. This can be achieved by reversing the factor levels:

```
dcast(setDT(df)[order(-Date)], ID ~ forcats::fct_rev(rowid(ID, prefix = "Order")))
```

> ```
>    ID Order4 Order3 Order2 Order1
> 1:  A     15     10      5     20
> 2:  B     NA     NA      8      9
> 3:  C     NA      5      2      6
> ```

Finally, we can get rid of the `NA` values by coercing to character:

```
dcast(setDT(df)[order(-Date)], ID ~ forcats::fct_rev(rowid(ID, prefix = "Order")), 
      toString)
```

> ```
>    ID Order4 Order3 Order2 Order1
> 1:  A     15     10      5     20
> 2:  B                    8      9
> 3:  C             5      2      6
> ```

Now, this reproduces nearly exactly OP's expected result.

#### Caveat

If there are more than 9 orders per `ID`, the column names need to be modified to maintain the correct order of columns:

```
dcast(setDT(df)[order(-Date)], ID ~ forcats::fct_rev(sprintf("Order%02i", rowid(ID))), 
      toString)
```

The format specifier `%02i` in the call to `sprintf()` ensures that the order number uses always two digits when converted to character. Compare `sort(as.character(1:10))` vs `sort(sprintf("%02i", 1:10))`.